# atom.io, hydrogen and ipython remote (ssh) kernel

Tags: python, ssh, ipython, atom-editor, hydrogen

So I discovered lately this [`atom.io`](https://atom.io) text editor. Soon after the amazing [`hydrogen`](https://github.com/willwhitney/hydrogen). So far so good, `hydrogen` starts an `ipython` kernel if it isn't already running and then it gives you real time interaction, just like with `ipython` notebook.

Good, but does anyone know if it's possible for `hydrogen` to be set up to work with a remote `ipython` kernel? The way I thought I could make this work is to have a local kernel be a communication layer between `hydrogen` and the remote kernel, but I don't see any way to do this. Do you have any idea how to set this up?

Comment: Why did you associate your question with the tags `atom` (the news feed format) and `ssh` ?

Comment: atom, because this is connected with the `atom.io` text editor and ssh because I'm talking about setting up a communication between `atom.io`'s plugin, `hydrogen` and a remote kernel over `ssh`... isn't that correct?

Comment: In this case, the atom tag you referenced was about the the XML-based news feed format. And since your question did not mention ssh, it wasn't clear.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, didn't know that atom refers to that `XML` thing...

Comment: If anyone is interested, after some digging around I came up with a solution which you can find on in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/razvanc87/a365b921ba4bf575b6a5). I'd like to mention though that after playing around with the `atom` editor I wasn't pleased enough and went back to `neovim` which I'm going to stick with for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

Hydrogen is able to connect to remote kernels running locally or on a server since version 0.12.

Checkout our [documentation](https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/docs/Usage/RemoteKernelConnection.html) for more infos.